# JSP page can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I'm trying to make a simple web page with JSP. My problem is that no resource as image or CSS is found, whatever the URL I use.

**My JSP is as simple as following :**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="img/logo.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

        <div id="banner">
            <div id="banner-wrapper">
                <div id="appname">
                    <a href="" >
                    <img alt="logo-cloudapi" height="50px" src="/logo.png">
                    </a>
                    ABC
                </div>
                <div id="a">
                    <img alt="logo2" height="50px" src="/logo2.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I tried following URL :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css">
```

Nothing works.

**Here is the structure of my src folder :**

[image: structure]

I'm not using web.xml but java config files.

Configuration:

```
package com.websystique.springmvc.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Initializer

```
package com.orange.paddock.gofr.provider.ihm.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class HelloWorldInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HelloWorldConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

I've already found many threads about this subject but no one works for me.

What could be the solution please ?

Comment: put your resources into resouces-directory, so that all the things are automatically becomes reachable(aka, on class path) and will resolve easily.

Comment: You mean the resource folder in src/main ?
Which URL should I use if I put it there ?

Comment: then directly refer it likewise, css/something.css or images.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your static resources on a url using mvc static resources.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/, /WEB-INF/static/" />
```

For example :

(xml conf)

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

(java based conf)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("(/resources/");    
    }
}
```

Anyway, placing them inside webapp should be enough.

Comment: Where do I put this line ?

Answer (score 0):

What is your project structure ?

"All static files like HTML, css, javascript will be placed directly under web application root directory. If we want to make these files secure, we need to place these files under WEB-INF directory."

"All JSP files can be placed directly inside a root directory or inside sub folders of WEB-INF folder. When placed inside WEB-INF or its sub folders"

Comment: I've tried this. I put everything inside WEB-INF folder, but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think the folder that has the webapps resources e.g .html, .jsp files as well as the css and js is wrongly referenced. Check your folder paths. That shoud work eg: `<link href="path to your css folder/styles.css">`